# Get span and match from finditer

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want obtain the tuple in *span* and the str of *macht*, but i dont know how acces to this object, the methods from the documentation dont work

```
import re

s = 'sd(asdf(xf))fg'

if re.findall('\([A-z ]+\)', s):

    m = re.finditer('\([A-z ]+\)', s)
    m = list(m)

print(m)
```

I get this output:

```
[<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(7, 11), match='(xf)'>]
```

What process or method i need for get *(7, 11)* and *'(xf)'*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import re

s = 'sd(asdf(xf))fg'

for x in re.finditer('\([A-z ]+\)', s):
    print((x.start(), x.end()), x.group())

#output

(7, 11) (xf)
```

Comment: You saved my life, thanks¡,
this is a little complicate

Comment: glad I could help!